# Do I need mysqli->real_escape_string after filter url?

Tags: php, session, get, mysqli

I'm asking this question because I'm still not quite sure if filter $_GET variable is enough to prevent mysql injection, so at first I have a filter function

```
function filter_url($url)
{
  if (is_array($url))
  {
    foreach ($url as $key => $value)
    {
      // recurssion
      $url[$key] = filter_url($value);
    }
    return $url;
  }
  else
  {
    // remove everything except for a-ZA-Z0-9_.-&=
    $url = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-&=]/', '', $url);
    return $url;
  }
}
```

I have `$_GET=filter_url($_GET);` everytime before I call

```
$filter_case =isset($_GET['product_ID'])?"and product_ID={$_GET['product_ID']}":"";
```

Do I need to do `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['product_ID'])` ? If I still have to imply it, what kind of sql injection will overpass my query method?

Besides, is it important to do `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['member_ID'])` that I'm thinking of is anyone possible to manipulate his `$_SESSION`  variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially wrong question to ask.

You need `$mysqli->real_escape_string` **when adding a string literal into SQL query.** In such a case you need this function **regardless of whatever string source or validation.** In any other case (ie string goes not in query or not as SQL string) this function going to be absolutely useless.

This is why it is essential to use **prepared statements**, either native or emulated.

Comment: I concur: prepared statements is the solution against SQL injection which work in all cases.

Comment: now I see that prepared statement has auto escape which I had missed out at pass since did not scrolled down to the end of manual. Changing my code to prepared statement! :)